# How to make a terminal scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, jscrollpane

I have these library [1] implemented in my web UI. The problem is that the
provided text is rendered to a buffer first and then only the visible parts are transfered
to the terminal display buffers. 
So I want to make the terminal to be scrollable.

How should I proceed?

[1] - http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/

Answer (score 0):

Quite a vague problem description, but I think this CSS will be of help.

```
\* {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work! I tried to add "overflow: scroll" to the termlib css style but it doesn't work. Do you have another idea?

Comment: That's a shame. Try appending the data to a `<textarea>` instead of a `div`?

Comment: I prefer to write a function to make terminal srollable. I want something simple, without zoom functions or others.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this answer is several years after the question, but applying overflow can simply be done via javascript after the `term` object has been created:

```
document.getElementById("termDiv").style.overflow = "scroll";
```